# What shevet did a convert in the midbar belong to (if any)?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism, shevatim-12-tribes

During the time in the midbar or when the land of Israel was apportioned by shevet, if someone converted what tribe (if any) would s/he belong to?

The purpose of this question is to deduce a converts status in the midbar in relation to things like where they camped (h/t @ari a) whom they could marry, etc.

Comment: @ Moshe: You might want to change this to "Where did they camp?" (and if not, then I'm going to ask that, so please say if you are or are not changing it)

Comment: @AriA I was asking to get a better understanding of how a ger in the midbar dealt with all the shevet-associated parts of life. Should I change the title of the question or was the edit in the explanation good enough?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[The *Chidushe Ham'iri* to *B'rachos* 20:2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=31518&pgnum=76) says that the *Keni* got land in Israel and calls it "*nat'lu chelek baaretz*", which makes it sound like he considers it on a par with anyone else's land. They got it in *Y'richo*, which was in *Binyamin*. I don't know whether there were any other converts in the *midbar* (or during the fourteen years of capturing the land, except maybe the *N'sinim*).

---

However, see the comments to this answer.

Comment: Even the Kenim were given this land only on an interim basis, though - until the Beis Hamikdash was built (Sifri to Num. 10:32).

Answer (score 1):

A convert does not belong to any Shevet.

Comment: +1 I don't know why this was downvoted but it could certainly be made more useful if you added a source.

Comment: If the question would explain as to why it may be different in the Midbar then it would be easier to answer more appropriately. The way the question is worded now, this answer is sufficient, although I guess someone did not like it.

Comment: I'm with @HodofHod: This answer is not sufficient without a source. As of now you have a %50 chance of having guessed correctly. (I happen to think you have; but that's not what this site is based on.)

Comment: Also, he did explain why he wants to know about the midbar or in Israel: he wants to know which land would they get. That's pretty clear in the question. (EDIT: And I wrote this about the first version of the question, although now it's even clearer.)

Comment: I do not think this is 100% correct, because I think they became part of which ever tribe they married into.

Comment: @avi That would likely depend on gender, as 'tribalness' usually travel paternally. Additionally, I'm even not sure if a female convert who married a Jew from, say, Levi really did become a Levitess; maybe only her kids were (nafka minah if she gets divoriced, can she still recieve maaser rishon).

Comment: @DoubleAA I believe that it did not matter which gender they were. The important part was to keep the land within the tribe.